# Where to put Middle Name in Google API user creation

Tags: c#, google-api, google-directory-api

I'm having the following issue and want to know the best solution for this:

I have an user I'm creating on my system this one contains: First, Middle and Last Name. 
When I create the User Object given by Google in their DLL I saw that they only provide GivenName and FamilyName Fields.

My question: It will be better to attach MiddleName to the GivenName or to FamilyName.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge; FamilyName should only consist of 1 name, therefore the middlename should be appended to GivenName.